# Generate random pupil math problems

Tags: c++, math

I try to use c++ to build a program for kids to practice their math. The problem should include addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. These 10 problems are randomly generated. Also, Randomly generate numbers for problems. However, must ensure that both the problem and result are no longer than two digits. The problem and the result should be greater or equal to zero. The divisor cannot be zero.

My implement is followed.

```
        while(prob_cout < 10){
            int op = rand() % 4; // range 0-3 to match a operation
            int answer, userGuess;
            if (op == 0) { // addition
                int number1 = rand() % 100; // problem no langer than two digits 
                int number2 = rand() % 100;  // range 0-99 
                answer = number1 + number2;
                if (answer >= 0 && answer < 100) { // valid problem: result also no more than two digits
                    prob_cout++;
                    cout << number1 << " + " << number2 << " = ";
                    cin >> userGuess;
                    // record problem info
                    prob_record.push_back(number1);
                    prob_record.push_back(op);
                    prob_record.push_back(number2);
                    prob_record.push_back(answer);
                    prob_record.push_back(userGuess);
                    // check answer
                    if (answer == userGuess)
                        user_scores += 10;
                    else
                        continue;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
            else if(op == 1) { // subtraction
                int number1 = rand() % 100; // problem no langer than two digits 
                int number2 = rand() % 100;  // range 0-99 
                answer = number1 - number2;
                if (answer >= 0 && answer < 100) { // valid problem: result also no more than two digits
                    prob_cout++;
                    cout << number1 << " - " << number2 << " = ";
                    cin >> userGuess;
                    // record problem info
                    prob_record.push_back(number1);
                    prob_record.push_back(op);
                    prob_record.push_back(number2);
                    prob_record.push_back(answer);
                    prob_record.push_back(userGuess);
                    if (answer == userGuess)
                        user_scores += 10;
                    else
                        continue;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
            else if (op == 2) { // multiplication
                int number1 = rand() % 20; 
                int number2 = rand() % 20;   
                answer = number1 * number2;
                if (answer >= 0 && answer < 100) { // valid problem: result also no more than two digits
                    prob_cout++;
                    cout << number1 << " * " << number2 << " = ";
                    cin >> userGuess;
                    // record problem info
                    prob_record.push_back(number1);
                    prob_record.push_back(op);
                    prob_record.push_back(number2);
                    prob_record.push_back(answer);
                    prob_record.push_back(userGuess);
                    // check answer
                    if (answer == userGuess)
                        user_scores += 10;
                    else
                        continue;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
            else if (op == 3) { //dividion
                int number1 = rand() % 100; 
                int number2 = rand() % 50; 
                answer = number1 / number2;
                if (answer >= 0 && answer < 100 && number1 > number2) { // valid problem: result also no more than two digits
                    prob_cout++;
                    cout << number1 << " / " << number2 << " = ";
                    cin >> userGuess;
                    // record problem info
                    prob_record.push_back(number1);
                    prob_record.push_back(op);
                    prob_record.push_back(number2);
                    prob_record.push_back(answer);
                    prob_record.push_back(userGuess);
                    // check answer
                    if (answer == userGuess)
                        user_scores += 10;
                    else
                        continue;
                }
                else
                    continue;
            }
        }
```

But. I find this method can't ensure equal possiblity for these four operations. The addition and substraction are much more than multiplication and division!

Anyone get a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

I would be tempted to find a mathematical way to ensure the chosen values laid within the acceptable range.

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <string>

int random_number(int from, int to)
{
    thread_local static std::mt19937 mt{std::random_device{}()};
    return std::uniform_int_distribution<int>{from, to}(mt);
}

int main()
{
    std::string const ops = "+-*/";

    for(auto n = 0; n < 10; ++n)
    {
        int lhs;
        int rhs;

        auto op = ops[random_number(0, 3)];

        switch(op)
        {
            case '+':
                lhs = random_number(0, 99);
                rhs = random_number(0, 99 - lhs);
                if(random_number(0, 1))
                    std::swap(lhs, rhs);
                break;

            case '-':
                lhs = random_number(0, 99);
                rhs = random_number(0, lhs);
                break;

            case '*':
                lhs = random_number(1, 99);
                rhs = random_number(0, 99 / lhs);
                if(random_number(0, 1))
                    std::swap(lhs, rhs);
                break;

            case '/':
                rhs = random_number(1, 10);
                lhs = rhs * random_number(0, 10);
                break;
        }

        std::cout << (n < 9 ? " ":"") << (n + 1);
        std::cout << ": " << (lhs < 10 ? " ":"") << lhs;
        std::cout << " " << op;
        std::cout << " " << (rhs < 10 ? " ":"") << rhs;
        std::cout << " = " << '\n';
    }
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
 1:  1 * 27 = 
 2: 12 /  2 = 
 3:  1 + 94 = 
 4: 87 - 63 = 
 5:  1 -  1 = 
 6:  9 *  6 = 
 7: 39 - 39 = 
 8: 47 + 33 = 
 9: 21 /  3 = 
10: 49 + 48 =
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem requirements, such as `if(answer >= 0 && answer < 100)`, is more likely to be satisfied by addition and subtraction than than multiplication and division. That's why more of the latters' problems get rejected.

If you want to have an almost equal share for these operations, an easy fix would be to not select again the operator in each loop, but to keep the same operator and try again until an acceptable problem appears for the same operator.

To do this, first initialize the operator to some value, say -1, add select a new operator only in this case. On the other hand, when the problem is rejected for the already selected operator, you wont select a new operator. You will set `op = -1` only when a problem is generated and accepted, exactly near every place you set `prob_cout++;`

The overall structure would be:

```
int op = -1;
while(prob_cout < 10){
        if(op == -1) op = rand() % 4; // <-- dont select a new operation when op already selected
        int answer, userGuess;
        if (op == 0) { // addition
        // generate addition problem
        if (answer >= 0 && answer < 100) { // valid problem                   
        prob_cout++;
        op = -1; // <----- so that next iteration an new operator is randomly selected.
       // Place op = -1 near each prob_cout++ statement in your initial code.
```

Note that this is a suggestion to solve (quickly) the problem of balancing the frequencies of different operators. I think, however, that from a code quality point of view your code has room for improvement because it has a lot of repeated operations that can be factorized somehow. But that's another topic.